# Obtaining a resultant from the mapping of 2 variables

Tags: java, if-statement, mapping, case

I am looking for a way to take two variables `chipNum` and `channel` and map them into another variable `ComboPin`. `chipNum` can have a value of 1 - 5 and `channel` can be 0 - 23. Depending on the combination, something like:
`(1,9) -> (11)`
`(2,10) -> (37)`
`(3,15) -> (66)`

Note that chipNum and channel are of type String and I would like ComboPin to be of type String as well.

I am trying to avoid using a bunch of if statement conditions or case statements.

I have done some research and seen the hash mapping or `map.put()` but I have only seen this with one value being mapped to another. I am just looking for which direction I can go in doing this.

The resultant (ComboPin) would then be placed into my database. Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: You've got two **BIG** requirements here.  One for `ComboPin` to work in a `Map`, and the other to read-write to a database.  You might want to separate those questions and ask each separately.

Comment: A `map` maps one "value" (the _key_) to another, but the key can be any object, including an object that has two private fields such as `chipNum` and `channel`.  You can do this by defining your own class that holds these two values.  Make sure to override `equals` and `hashCode` in your class.

Comment: For the map, you need to make certain that you [override `equals()` and `hashCode()`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05273/) properly.

Comment: @markspace Im just looking for assistance for `ComboPin` to be mapped. I have the writing to the database handled. I was just giving an insight

Comment: @ajb I will go towards this direction of defining a class. I will let you guys know what I come up with

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want an easy translation between `chipNum`:`channel` and ComboPim. Is that right?

If so, you may easily concatenate both.

```
public String getComboPin( String chipNum, String channel){
    return chipNum + ":" + channel;
}
public String getChipNum( String comboPin ){
    return comboPin.split(":")[0];
}
public String getChannel( String comboPin ){
    return comboPin.split(":")[1];
}
```

Let me know if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: You have slightly misunderstood. `ComboPin` is independent from `chipNum` and `channel`. In my question, I showed three different examples of some values mapping to `ComboPin`. `(1,9) -> (11)`. 11 would be my ComboPin